# Installation of openpose inside a docker container - installation issues with the dockerfile

Tags: python-3.x, docker, deep-learning, containers, openpose

I want to install **openpose** through docker for python 3. For that, I am making a Dockerfile with all the commands and getting an error with the installation process.

I am trying to build the Dockerfile from scratch using this code.

```
FROM ubuntu
LABEL maintainer = "Ankit Sharma" <ankit.kumar@mirrorsize.com>

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y libopencv-dev
RUN apt install -y libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
RUN apt-get install -y libhdf5-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libgoogle-glog-dev
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y libboost-all-dev
RUN apt-get install -y wget

WORKDIR src

RUN git clone https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose.git

WORKDIR /src/openpose/3rdparty

RUN rm -r caffe
RUN rm -r pybind11

RUN git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
RUN git clone https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git

WORKDIR /src/openpose/build

RUN apt-get -y install cmake
RUN cmake .. -DBUILD_CAFFE=ON -DBUILD_python=ON -DGPU_MODE=CPU_ONLY -USE_OPENCV=ON
RUN make
RUN make install

RUN make -j 64
```

I expected a clean installation and `BUILD_python: ON` and `USE_OPENCV: ON`.

Here's the complete output:

```
--   Build type              :   Release
-- 
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS       :   on
--   BUILD_python            :   OFF
--   BUILD_matlab            :   OFF
--   BUILD_docs              :   OFF
--   CPU_ONLY                :   ON
--   USE_OPENMP              :   ON
--   USE_OPENCV              :   OFF
--   USE_LEVELDB             :   OFF
--   USE_LMDB                :   OFF
--   ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK       :   OFF
--   USE_SYSTEMTAP           :   OFF
--   PERFORMANCE_MONITORING  :   OFF
--   CO_SIM  :   OFF
-- 
--   Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (MKL)
--   MKL2017_SUPPORTED :   ON, is a default engine
--   MKLDNN_SUPPORTED :    ON, is a default engine
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.65)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 3.0.0)
--   CUDA              :   No
-- 
-- Install:
-- Install path      :   /src/openpose/build/caffe
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Other errors are coming in the Caffe build -

```
[ 39%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/mkldnn_eltwise_layer.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object 

src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/mkldnn_inner_product_layer.cpp.o
/src/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/src/caffe/layers/mkldnn_inner_product_layer.cpp: In member function 'void 

caffe::MKLDNNInnerProductLayer<Dtype>::InitInnerProductBwd(const std::vector<caffe::Blob<Dtype>*>&, const std::vector<bool>&, const std::vector<caffe::Blob<Dtype>*>&)':

/src/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/src/caffe/layers/mkldnn_inner_product_layer.cpp:357:2: error: this 'else' clause does not guard... [-Werror=misleading-indentation]
  else
  ^~~~

/src/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/src/caffe/layers/mkldnn_inner_product_layer.cpp:361:5: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the 'else'
     ipBwdData_desc.reset(new inner_product_backward_data::desc(init_bottom_md, init_weights_md, init_top_md));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: Typically if you're building a C program with a Python extension, you'll need the python3-dev packages; similarly for anything else the application depends on.